# PHP get the value of numrows data of <td> under the condition of while

Tags: php, html

I want to be able to send the value of the selected topic to another page by having a $_SESSION tag but it always gets the value of the last data in the database

```
$sqltpc = "SELECT * FROM forum_question";
$resulttpc = mysql_query($sqltpc) or die('Error: '.mysql_error());
while($linetpc = mysql_fetch_array($resulttpc, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
   echo "
    <tr id='trow' class='right'><input type='hidden' name='hidden' value=".$linetpc['id']." />
          <td><img src='Images/logosmallforum.png' /><a href='lentech_topic.php'>".$linetpc['id']." ".$linetpc['topic']."</a></td>
      <td><a href='#'>".$linetpc['username']."</a></td>
      <td><a href='#'>".$linetpc['view']."</a></td>
      <td><a href='#'>".$linetpc['reply']."</a></td>
    </tr>";
   }

$viewtpc = $_POST['hidden'];
$_SESSION['idset'] = $viewtpc;
```

Comment: So what do you want to?

Comment: How do you decide which value is selected?

Comment: Is it possible to select it using <a>

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that the `hidden` input is an array by having it written as:

```
<input type='hidden' name='hidden[]' value=".$linetpc['id']." />
```

Notice the square brackets? `$_POST['hidden']` will then be an array of all the values rather than just a string of the last in the list.

Note that you will actually have to post the form for this to take effect (your code at the moment suggests you haven't). If you don't plan to post the form then rather store the values in an input field as you've done you'd just add to the `$_SESSION['idset']` array within the loop:

```
$sqltpc = "SELECT * FROM forum_question";
$resulttpc = mysql_query($sqltpc) or die('Error: '.mysql_error());
while($linetpc = mysql_fetch_array($resulttpc, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

   $_SESSION['idset'][] = $linetpc['id'];

   echo "
    <tr id='trow' class='right'>
          <td><img src='Images/logosmallforum.png' /><a href='lentech_topic.php'>".$linetpc['id']." ".$linetpc['topic']."</a></td>
      <td><a href='#'>".$linetpc['username']."</a></td>
      <td><a href='#'>".$linetpc['view']."</a></td>
      <td><a href='#'>".$linetpc['reply']."</a></td>
    </tr>";
   }
```

Comment: it still doesn't get the the selected variable to lentech_topic.php

Comment: I got it! all was I need was the $_GET to get the variable's value to the other page. Thanks for the Replys and sorry for my late reply

Answer (score 0):

I got it! All that was needed was the `$_GET` to get the variable's value to the other page.

Thanks for the replys and sorry for my late reply